# Instagram does not show all comments of a media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram API to get a user media comments in my site.
I used this endpoint to get comments of specific media:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media_id}/comments?access_token={media_owner_access_token}
```

Variables:

`{media_id}` is media Instagram Id that Instagram gave to me, it's like:

```
1250190150128742954_182781845
```

`{media_owner_access_token}` is access token of media owner that when user registered in my site Instagram gave it to me it's like:

```
9857164750.81d09db.20b41a2a356d6442bav22d340a55e1f5g
```

When I try to get media comments for specific media of a user it will give me just media owner comments but this media contains other people comments on it too!

Is this how Instagram API works? Or I made a mistake here?
And for record I am in sandbox mode not live can it be cause of my problem!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am in sandbox mode not live can it be cause of my problem!?

Yes. In sandbox mode, the API will only return data from users who have been invited to your sandbox.

From the Instagram API docs:

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits

You'll need to get your app approved for live use, and request the proper scopes when generating your token.

See https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/ for more information.